# Accessing Ext Component Config

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a very simple extension in Ext JS from `Ext.form.Panel`:

```
Ext.define('path.to.SomeClass', {  
    extend : 'Ext.form.panel',  
    xtype : 'some-class'  

    config : {  
        hasDog : true  
    },

    constructor : function (config) {
        if (this.config.hasDog) {  
            // do something dog related
        } else {
            // do something not dog related
        }
    }
});
```

I then have a "container" for this custom componet:

```
Ext.define('path.to.OtherClass', {  
    extend : 'Ext.window.Window',  

    // ....

    items : [{
        xtype : 'some-class',
        hasDog : false
    }]
});
```

However, for some reason unknown to me, the `if...else` evaluation in `SomeClass` is always picking up the default configuration for `hasDog`. Am I not correctly configuring `some-class` in `OtherClass`'s `items` config?

To add a bit more context, `OtherClass` is called via some using code:

```
var window = Ext.create('path.to.OtherClass');  
window.show();
```

From what I can see, the above is pretty standard stuff - at least in thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you always get the default configuration is because you're accessing `this.config`, which is the declaration of your configuration, instead of the actual configuration from the constructor argument. So either use `config` or - once you've called the parent class constructor - `this`.

```
constructor : function (config) {
    // before parent class constructor or this.initConfig was called:
    console.log(config.hasDog);

    // call parent class constructor
    this.callParent(arguments);

    // after parent class constructor or this.initConfig was called:
    console.log(this.hasDog);
}
```

Also have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-config):

> **Note:** You need to make sure [Ext.Base.initConfig](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Base-method-initConfig) is called from your constructor if you are defining your own class or singleton, unless you are extending a Component. Otherwise the generated getter and setter methods will not be initialized.

In your case, since your extending a component, calling the parent constructor should suffice (as shown in the example above).

Comment: Matt, thanks, I saw that bit in the documentation after trying to make that call to `initConfig` and seeing an error logged to the console. Excellent answer, thank you.